# What is the right way to receive and store an sms in an android default sms app?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sms

My android app's primary purpose is to delete sms messages easily. Since from kitkat, there is a requirement that the app has to be the "default sms app", I ended up creating an app that has all the necessary receivers.

On the SMS Receiver, currently the app is receiving the sms and saving it, with the following code.

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            if (intent.Action != IntentAction) return;
            //context.SendOrderedBroadcast(intent, IntentAction);
            var bundle = intent.Extras;

            if (bundle == null) return;

            var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus");
            var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray<Java.Lang.Object>(pdus.Handle);

            var msgs = new SmsMessage[castedPdus.Length];

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++)
            {
                var bytes = new byte[JNIEnv.GetArrayLength(castedPdus[i].Handle)];
                JNIEnv.CopyArray(castedPdus[i].Handle, bytes);

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu(bytes);
                if (sender == null)
                    sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;
                sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress, System.Environment.NewLine, msgs[i].MessageBody));

                putSmsToDatabase(context, msgs[i]);                    

                Toast.MakeText(context, sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
    private void putSmsToDatabase(Context cntxt, SmsMessage sms)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.Put("ADDRESS", sms.OriginatingAddress);
        values.Put("DATE", sms.TimestampMillis);
        values.Put("READ", 0);
        values.Put("STATUS", sms.Status);
        values.Put("TYPE", 1);
        values.Put("SEEN", 0);            
        values.Put("BODY", sms.MessageBody);

        // Push row into the SMS table
        Android.Net.Uri inboxURI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/inbox");
        var uri = cntxt.ContentResolver.Insert(inboxURI, values);            
    }
```

This code seem to save it, but the problem is that none of the other sms apps shows these messages stored from my app. Everywhere that i searched for SMS receivers, saving part code is not really provided. Just the receiving the sms and the Toast display is provided. This created the below question.

1. As a default sms app, is it really necessary that my app should save the sms to "content://sms/inbox"?
2. If yes, What is wrong with the save shown in the above sample. I have a vague understanding that i may have something to do with conversation/threads. But, since i'm getting started with raw android development, probably i have understood it completely wrong. Tried creating the thread using thread_ids, which doesn't seem to work either.

This piece of the puzzle is stopping me from the roll out of the app. Please help.

Comment: All of my `values.Put` column names are lowercase, i.e. `values.Put("address", ......` I've never tried it with uppercase columns, but that would be a start.

Comment: "This code seem to save it" - Why do you think that? That is, what indication do you have that it's not just failing silently? What's the value of `uri` returned from the `ContentResolver.Insert()` call? Have you explicitly set your app as the default app? You're aware that there can be only one default app at a time, yeah?

Comment: @MikeM. When i reload my app, the sms gets displayed in the ListView, since i'm loading it from "content://sms/inbox". And Yes, my app is the default sms app. On the "OnResume" on MainReciever, i'm setting this up, calling the intent. Android displays the dialog and my app becomes the default.

Comment: @SushiHangover I didn't thought the columns were case-sensitive. It seems to save (please see my above comment). Anyway, i will try with lowercase values and come back with the URI return value. BTW, i'm debugging this multiple real devices, not an emulator.

Comment: Well, that's kind of odd. What happens if you set another app as the default after yours has saved some messages, and refresh its list? Can you see them then? Can you still see them in your app when it's not the default?

Comment: Yes, it is odd :) I cannot see the messages stored from my app on the other app's view. This led me to the thinking that, probably i had to save the messages with a thread id. I tried to get the thread for the address and then saved the sms with that thread_id. No luck, there too.

Comment: @SushiHangover changing the column/key names to lower case did the trick. The code always returned the uri regardless of the case of the key, something like "content://sms/43". 

I found something else too. I had the default app and the newly installed "Skype Lite" app. The Skype Lite is showing me the text messages, regardless oh the case of the key. Lowercase or upper case, both works fine. In the default app, it is showing the messages only when the sms is saved using lowercase keys. Anyways, thank you for the tip. That solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @MikeM and SushiHangover. Appreciate the help. Have to figure out how to mark a comment as answer.

Comment: That's interesting. I can't really reconcile how that's working, exactly. SQLite is indeed case-insensitive for names by default, but even if your Provider isn't standard, it's odd that the regular default would somehow distinguish by case. Sounds like multiple instances of weirdness on your device. Anyhoo, you can't accept a comment. @SushiHangover will have to post an answer, if they like. Cheers!

Comment: I added an answer based upon the lowercase column names... It appears that the provider does not produce case-insensitive sql statements, I stopped digging into the ASOP code when someone pointed out the provider's usage was not documented until API19 and that the column names are provided as constants now and that before that, you should perform a `getColumnNames` to obtain them (and even then they are always lowercase and have been since the SMS ContentResolver introduction as a  "private" api... learn something new everyday..... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All column names should be lowercased as it appears that the `Sms ContentResolver` is constructing  "quoted" column strings within the sql statement.

While the statements:

```
values.Put("ADDRESS", sms.OriginatingAddress);
```

and

```
values.Put("address", sms.OriginatingAddress);
```

*Should* resolve to a SQL statement that is case insensitive, it is not.

Thus you should provide the columns names as returned from `Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns` (which are all lowercase):

Your code becomes:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.Put("address", sms.OriginatingAddress);
~~~
```

If your app is targeting a min. of API19:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.Put(Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.Address, sms.OriginatingAddress);
~~~
```

The SMS ContentProvider was not publicly documented until API 19(?):

`Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns`: [TextBasedSmsColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html)